# Is human blood useful as food?

Tags: hematology, nutrition, digestion

Lacking other resources, could a healthy adult slit his wrist to feed a starving child with his blood? Would it be nutritional and would a starving dehydrated child eat it?

Comment: Interesting... but hopingly just a hypothetical situation? Seems platelets (coagulating blood corpuscle) and immunoglobulins may cause problem.

Comment: High amount of minerals ( iron for example) could show their toxic effects.

Comment: Yes, blood is nutritious, and whether a child would drink it is up to the child. It's not exactly palatable in large quantities; it's warm, and coagulation renders it gooey relatively quickly. It should help in dehydration (the degree depending on the cause of dehydration) because it's isotonic. The Maasai drink blood from their cattle instead of slaughtering them for meat. All that being said, the adult, if not pretty careful, will not be able to care for the child, and they'll both die.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused do human enterocytes have receptors also for other classes of Ig, than for IgA? Do you believe that the number of Ab resorbed this way could cause a life threatening problem? 
Also, Ig are quite stable molecules, but wouldn't most of the platelet compounds get digested in stomach? 

Just a note: in our culture (middle-east europe) it's common to eat pre-cooked blood from swine and it's considered quite nutritious and delicious meal. (pre-cooking however means that most of the mentioned proteins are probably already denatured )